# Reporting Services Preview Host has stopped working

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, ssrs-2014

I am having an issue previewing SSRS reports using Visual Studio Professional 2013.  The first time I preview a report it works, however, if I go back to design and then preview again I get the following error:

[image: Reporting Services Preview Processing Host has stopped working]

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   PreviewProcessingService.exe
Problem Signature 02:   12.0.2430.0
Problem Signature 03:   543f04a1
Problem Signature 04:   mscorlib
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.34209
Problem Signature 06:   534894cc
Problem Signature 07:   4780
Problem Signature 08:   57
Problem Signature 09:   System.OutOfMemoryException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

When I close the program I get the following error:

[image: Visual Studio First Error]
If I try to preview the report again, I get the following error:
[image: No endpoint listening]
I have verified that net.pipe listener service is running, and I've tried restarting it.  I have uninstalled Visual Studio and SQL Server and installed it again.  None of these have fixed the problem.  What can I do to allow myself to preview a report more than once without restarting Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any definite answer, I assumed that the data set was too big, hence the System.OutOfMemoryException.  That being said, after ensuring that the SQL for the dataset returned the smallest set of data possible, I seemed to be able to run my reports.  I do wonder, what is the correlation between SQL Server system resourced and SSRS dataset size?

Answer (score 1):

This is *actually* a problem with the way Visual Studio 2013 implements the preview.

The first time you click preview in the 2013 IDE, a cmd window opens that is the preview Process that VS uses to generate the preview

[image]

there will be one of these cmd windows for each report you are previewing.

If you close **ANY** of these cmd windows, you will receive the error above next time you attempt to preview **ANY** report.

You need to restart VS inorder to get rid of this error.

Comment: I am aware of the command prompt coming up.  This wasn't the problem.  In fact, I thought it was weird that I didn't see this.  Unfortunately I have given in and wiped my computer.  All problems are now solved